# How do I use wget or CURL in php to grab a snapshot of a web page with an asterick * in its URL? (Wayback Machine archive.org question)

Tags: php, wget, curl, special-characters, httrack

The following web page on the Wayback Machine (archive.org) has an asterick * in its URL:
https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.nasa.gov/

Neither CURL nor wget will allow me to grab the page.  I am using the latest version of Linux Mint (2018).

How do I use wget or CURL in php to grab a snapshot of a web page with an asterick * in its URL, specifically https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.nasa.gov/?

Thanks!  Might httrack work?

EDIT: Open the site web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://www.nasa.gov in a browser. Then compare it with what you see with the wget command. Are they the same? For me the wget command just returns a generic page.

Comment: Works for me. What are you trying to run, and what happens when you do? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Open the site web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://www.nasa.gov in a browser. Then compare it with what you see with the wget command you used above. Are they the same? For me the wget just returns a generic page.

Comment: I don't think that's the asterisk's doing, just that they don't want you crawling it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I don't want to crawl it.  I just want a single snapshot of that page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me, as long as the URL is enclosed in quotation marks.

If you want to avoid the message "Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP", the easiest thing to do is to replace the asterisk with its [percent-encoded equivalent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1):

```
wget "https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://www.nasa.gov"
```

Comment: Open the site https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://www.nasa.gov in a browser.  Then compare it with what you see with the wget command you used above.  Are they the same?  For me the wget just returns a generic page.